# Regex that will match first case on every line.

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I've got the following Regex:

```
.*?,
```

And here is some of the data I am working with:

```
"bagel-mssql-iscsi.private.hostname.ca","3636634643","8.8.8.8"
"cecs-admin.prt.hostname.ca","3636634643","8.8.8.8"
"cecs-admin2.prt.hostname.ca","3636634643","8.8.8.8"
```

*The above data has been censored from the original data.*

I want to match:

```
"bagel-mssql-iscsi.private.hostname.ca",
"cecs-admin.prt.hostname.ca",
"cecs-admin2.prt.hostname.ca",
```

The problem is that my regex is also matching the numerical value after the hostnames. What can I do so that only the first occurrence of every line is matched. Or an alternative method that would work with this type of data also would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would be,

```
^".*?",
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mN8kN0/3)

**Explanation:**

- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `"` Literal double quotes.
- `.*?` Reluctant match of any character zero or more times.
- `",` Literal `"` followed by a comma.

Answer (score 1):

You need to anchor to the beginning of the line:

```
^.*?,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `^` anchor which matches only at the beginning of the line:

```
^.*?,
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Regex Filter below may help:

```
^\"(\S*?)\",
```

http://regex101.com/r/dZ3gH8/1